# $\theta_0=1$ in MA process

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

Let $X_t$ be an MA$(q)$ process defined as
\begin{equation}
X_{t}=\mu +\overset{q}{\underset{j=0}{\sum }}\theta_{j}\varepsilon_{t-j}=\mu +\theta_{0}\varepsilon_{t}+\theta_{1}\varepsilon_{t-1}+\theta_{2}\varepsilon_{t-2} + \ldots
\end{equation}
where we ask that $\theta_0=1$. This requirement is for "identifiability purpose". What does the latter mean mathematically I cannot find any explicit and rigorous explanation of why we ask that $\theta_0=1$

Comment: Hi: I answered this question on stats.stackexchange.